# Show component or hide

Tags: vue.js, quasar-framework

```html
<q-dialog
  v-model="filterModal"
  position="left"
  full-height
  maximized
>
  <object-mobile-filter />
</q-dialog>
```

I have an `<object-mobile-filter />` component and if **filterModal** is false, then the model window is hidden, and the component itself is killed, is it possible to make it so that when the window is `hidden`, the `component` itself get hide and when `filterModal = true`, a new component gets created.

Answer (score 1):

If the `filterModal` is always `boolean` (or it has truthy or falsy values) you can simply use `v-if` to [conditionally render](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) the component base on the value of `filterModal`.

```html
<q-dialog
  v-model="filterModal"
  position="left"
  full-height
  maximized
>
  <object-mobile-filter v-if="filterModal" />
</q-dialog>
```

Comment: I need to use this component within the framework of q-dialog, this is a modal window where it is displayed and when closing this window and opening it again, the component is re-rendered

Comment: @Alexey I presumed that you want to conditional load the `<object-mobile-filter />` within `<q-dialog />`. You can put the `v-if` statement on the `q-dialog` too if you want to conditionally render the whole dialog. If you seek something else please elaborate on it because I did not understand what you want.